# PHP SQLite Не записывает данные в базу

Tags: php, linux, sqlite

интересная ситуация.
Написал небольшой чат на PHP с авторизацией перед каждой отправкой сообщения, но это не суть.
На локальном компьютере всё работало хорошо, данные из базы читались и в базу записывались,
а вот когда загрузил всё на сервер, работать не перестал только скрипт по чтению данных из БД.
Система - Linux Debian11
Php7.4, Установлена php7.4-sqlite. На файле базы данных стоит 777 разрешение.
Сам Php скрипт отрабатывает хорошо, без ошибок, но данные в базе не появляются
Пожалуйста, помогите. Ниже скрипт

```
<?php
// Установите соединение с базой данных SQLite
$db = new PDO('sqlite:database.db');

// Получаем данные из POST-запроса
$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Проверяем, существует ли пользователь с таким никнеймом
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname = :nickname';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname);
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$user) {
  if(!($password == "") && !($nickname == "") && !($message == ""))
  {
    // Если пользователь не существует, создаем нового пользователя
    $insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO users (nickname, password) VALUES (:nickname, :password)';
    $insertStmt = $db->prepare($insertQuery);
    $insertStmt->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname);
    $insertStmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $insertStmt->execute();
    $insertMessageQuery = 'INSERT INTO messages (nickname, message) VALUES (:nickname, :message)';
        $insertMessageStmt = $db->prepare($insertMessageQuery);
        $insertMessageStmt->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname);
        $insertMessageStmt->bindParam(':message', $message);
        $insertMessageStmt->execute();
        $report = "";

// Преобразование отчета в JSON
$response = array('report' => $report);
$responseJson = json_encode($response);

// Возвращение отчета в JSON формате
echo $responseJson;
  }
  else{
    $report = "Не оставляйте поля пустыми!";

// Преобразование отчета в JSON
$response = array('report' => $report);
$responseJson = json_encode($response);

// Возвращение отчета в JSON формате
echo $responseJson;
    exit;
  }
} else {
    // Проверяем правильность пароля
    if ($user['password'] === $password) {
        $insertMessageQuery = 'INSERT INTO messages (nickname, message) VALUES (:nickname, :message)';
        $insertMessageStmt = $db->prepare($insertMessageQuery);
        $insertMessageStmt->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname);
        $insertMessageStmt->bindParam(':message', $message);
        $insertMessageStmt->execute();
        $report = "";

// Преобразование отчета в JSON
$response = array('report' => $report);
$responseJson = json_encode($response);

// Возвращение отчета в JSON формате
echo $responseJson;
    } else {
        // Возвращаем ошибку, если пароль неверный
        $report = "Пользователь уже зарегистрирован - вы ввели неверный пароль.";

        // Преобразование отчета в JSON
        $response = array('report' => $report);
        $responseJson = json_encode($response);
        
        // Возвращение отчета в JSON формате
        echo $responseJson;
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ошибки проверь. Все методы PDO могут либо бросать эксепшены, либо возвращать какой-нибудь `false`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Спустя 6 часов изнурительных поисков ошибки, выяснил, что проблема была в пакете - php. Я по глупости, решил, что если установлю сразу все пакеты, будет лучше, но оказалось, что они конфликтуют. Всем спасибо за помощь

Comment: Хорошо что все получилось!)  А лайкосик мог-бы и поставить, хотя-бы за стремление помочь решить проблему )

Comment: @EugenX :) Да я пытался поставить, но что-то не получилось, разбираться не стал)) Написано было, что голоса новичков не учитываются

Answer (score 0):

А ты права доступа проверил на файл базы? Сервер писать то туда может?

```
$ touch database.db
$ chown пользователь:группа database.db
```

Возможные варианты пользователя и группы

- `apache:apache` для Apache Web Server
- `nginix:nginix` для nginix
- `httpd:httpd`   ну или так

Узнать наверняка можно в списке процессов написав `ps -aux`, ну или методом научного тыка перепровыва все три варианта :)

**Добавленно спустя**

Временно включи вывод ошибок. По умолчанию он подавляет ошибки.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Проверь `php.ini`

Должно быть включено

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=sqlite3
```

Возможно PDO не может стартануть драйвер?

Третяя строчка `$db = new PDO('sqlite:database.db');` сделай путь польным `'sqlite:'.__DIR__.'/database.db'` возможно он пытается сохранить файл не там где ты ожидаешь?

Если всё выше перечисленное не помогло, идём в php.ini и временно включаем

`display_startup_errors on`

Тогд он просто обязан будет что-нибуть да рассказать тебе :)

Comment: "На файле базы данных стоит 777 разрешение"

Comment: @u_mulder Дополнил ответ, пробуйте... Я вариаций много накидал )

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Дошел до последнего пункта. А где мне просматривать вывод ошибок из PHP? На HTML странице не отображаются, после вызова php, а напрямую php запустить не могу - "Страница недоступна".  Может раз не отображаются, значит их и нет? Читать ведь базу я спокойно могу через php. в логах Апача есть только вот такие строки php7 error

Comment: По умолчанию PHP выводит ошибки в STDERR, куда он перенаправлен зависит от конфигурации сервера. К примеру Apache свои ошибки сохраняет в `/var/log/httpd-error.log` а так как PHP запускается из под Apache то и STDERR у них общий. Так-же бывают извращенные методы соединения, например PHP запускаеться как PHP7FPM сервер, тогда у него будет свой собственный лог

Comment: @u_Mulder кстати 0777 доступ делает весь сервер уязвимым, лично мой совет все-же менять владельца а не права!

Comment: @EugeneX Да сервер тестовый, в отчаянии просто уже 777 поставил. Лог STDERR пустой, а Apache2 выводит только PHP error. Забыл уточнить важный момент - писал код я на Винде, тестировал на MAMP и всё отлично работало. А вот на Линуксе не работает. Чувствую, что не хаватает чего-то. Сам код PHP кстати, работает, не идёт только запись в DB, а чтение проходит

Comment: @Иван STDERR это не лог, это pipe. У всех приложений даже оконных даже в windows при запуске создаются 3 пайпа - STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR. По сути это 3 текстовых буфера. STDIN отвечает за ввод текста в программу. STDOUT - вывод текста из программы. STDERR - за вывод ошибок из программы. Обычные консольные приложения их использую как ввод/вывод в консоль в оконных приложениях эти папйпы обычно перенаправляются в абстрактные получатели.